# TypeScript function generic types intersection does not behave correctly

Tags: typescript

```
interface A {
  a: number;
}

let myVar: A = {
  a: 123
};

myVar = Object.assign({}, myVar, {
  b: 456
});
```

Why does TypeScript not complain about that re-assignment of `myVar` via the `Object.assign()` call?

Given that the type definition for that `Object.assign()` call is:

```
assign<T, U, V>(target: T, source1: U, source2: V): T & U & V;
```

...and the (return type) intersection of the three types in my call doesn't match `interface A`, shouldn't the compiler pick that up?

The problem is not related to TypeScript not being able to infer the types in the function call, because if I change the code to:

```
interface A {
  a: number;
}

interface B {
  b: number;
}

interface C {}

let myVar: A = {
  a: 345
};

myVar = Object.assign<C, A, B>({}, myVar, {
  b: 345
});
```

...it still doesn't complain.

**I'm using TypeScript 2.2.1 and the "noImplicitAny" compiler flag is set to "true".**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The basic rule for TypeScript’s structural type system is that x is compatible with y if y has at least the same members as x

Applying this rule to your example - `A` is compatible with `A&B&C`:

```
let abc:A&B&C = {a:123, b:456};
```

And assignment `let a:A = abc;` is perfectly valid.

More info [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)

Comment: I find this answer confusing, albeit it did get me thinking about the real reason. I think my answer is more concise and accurate.

Comment: I've put a quote from official typescript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html). What exactly is confusing?

Comment: That sentence in the context of the documentation page you linked, does make sense, but it is confusing and misleading in the context of this question. I apologize for the downvote, I tried to get rid of it, because you did help me find the answer, but it won't let me.

Answer (score 0):

> `A & B` is assignable to `X` if `A` is assignable to `X` or `B` is assignable to `X`.

Given that TypeScript uses a [structural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), the reason there is no error is because the re-assignment of `myVar` gets the properties from the source/original `myVar` (second argument) and is satisfied from then on. So any other objects that get mixed in (e.g. first and third arguments), are irrelevant when it comes to satisfying the type of `myVar`.

[Quote source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3622)

Comment: There's no X in your example. `myVar` is defined as `A`, so it for sure can store a value of type `A&B`

Comment: I know there is no `X` in my example, I was trying to relate `X` from the quote, to an equivalent (`myVar`) in my example.

Comment: `X` in your example is `A`, so => A & B is assignable to A if A is assignable to A or B is assignable to A

Comment: You've lost me and I think you are mistaken. I'm pretty sure `X` refers to a variable and not a type in that context.

Comment: The wrong point in your answer is that you're relating `myVar`(variable) to `X`(type).

Comment: You're correct, my apologies. I shall update my answer.