# How to achieve statically typed immutable redux state tree in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

Using TypeScript + Redux and being able to define a statically typed immutable state tree like so:

```
interface StateTree {
  readonly subState1: SubState1;
  readonly subState2: SubState2;
}

interface SubState1 {
  readonly a: number;
  readonly b: string;
}

interface SubState2 {
  readonly c: {
    readonly d: symbol;
    readonly e: string;
  };
}
```

...is fantastic, because it largely avoids the need for libraries such as [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) and allows for strong assurances around accessing that read-only state tree, like so:

```
const state: StateTree = getState();
state.subState2.c.e
```

**Yet, is there a way to maintain the immutability and type-safety, when it comes to creating modified copies of the read-only state trees?**

I thought `Object.assign()` would be up to the task (and it is from an immutability point of view), but it loses out on compile-time type-safety because of TypeScript's type intersection behaviour ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475907/typescript-function-generic-types-intersection-does-not-behave-correctly/)).

Answer (score 1):

I made the React & Redux rookie mistake of not paying enough attention to immutability when I was first setting up my project and now I'm starting to look at retrofitting it in.  Ugh.  I've been evaluating different approaches with a very high emphasis on preserving TypeScript's strong typing.  I didn't get very far into Immutable.js because I didn't see a way of preserving type checking with it, at least not in my project.  Then I stumbled across upon ImmutableAssign

https://github.com/engineforce/ImmutableAssign

One of ImmutableAssign's stated design goals is to play nicely with TypeScript and so far that seems to be working out for me quite well.  It also seems to behave in exactly the way that I was hoping in that changing a property way down on a deeply nested chain of object changes the references of all the objects in the path.  Unfortunately I haven't gotten far enough along in my project's makeover to really comment on ImmutableAssign's performance characteristics.  Still, you might want to give it a look.

Comment: It's definitely an alternative, but I'm personally not a fan of the mechanism (even though the API is less invasive). TypeScript has become more intelligent with regard to the spread operator and I've found that it works quite well for type-safety (even though the boilerplate builds up in proportion to the nesting, but that's just what you get for using languages that don't have baked-in support for immutability).

Answer (score 0):

`readonly` is a good tool in the immutability toolbox but it is only enforced at compile time.

`immutable.js` goes one step further by guaranteeing immutability at runtime

There is no magic wand (I know of) that both provides deep cloning and type "safety". `Object.assign` provide shallow copying (only) but this proves usually sufficient for states in Redux.

I disagree that `Object.assign` looses compile time safety. The structural type system of Typescript will check compatibility by guaranteeing that all mandatory members are actually assigned, hence

```
interface State {
    a: number;
}

const myVar = Object.assign({}, {b: 456}) as State;
```

will not compile because `a` is missing in `myVar`

Comment: The main point of using TypeScript is to get compile-time guarantees, hence I'm not looking for run-time immutability guarantees, I'm looking for the compile-time guarantees. As I mentioned in an answer for the other/linked question, you will find that your code does indeed compile without error.

Comment: No, this code does not compile: check the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20interface%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20myVar%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20%7Bb%3A%20456%7D)%20as%20State%3B)

Comment: My mistake, it does, but try doing something like this `Object.assign({}, state, {b: 456});`, where `state` is of type `State` and it will compile, for some reason.

Comment: That is how the structural type system works in Typescript (and most other languages btw): the new var is 'compatible' with State, even though you "augmented" it with `b`, because it has all the members of State

Comment: Right, thanks, that makes sense to me now, but unfortunately my question still remains unanswered.

Comment: I do not get it. Why does it matter that you *may* have more properties in State when you can already guarantee that you have **all** the properties that are required ?

Comment: Say I try to re-assign `subState1`, but I accidentally do this: `Object.assign({}, state, { subState3: abc })`. Yes the result still has all the necessary properties to satisfy `StateTree`, but the code was supposed to re-assign the `subState1` property, not add a new one. I was hoping the type system would be able to catch that problem, but given that you reminded me of TypeScript's type system nature, I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3823) discussion, I came to the conclusion that my original thoughts on `Object.assign()` falling short because of TypeScript's type intersection, were misplaced because of the following:

## TypeScript's type intersection was not the root of my original issue, object assignment was.

I was dwelling on type intersection, when this is the root cause:

```
interface Combined {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

interface A {
  a: number;
}

interface B {
  b: string;
}

const temp1: Combined = {
  a: 1,
  b: '2'
};

const temp2: A = temp1;
```

...which has no type intersection involved.

## An interface is an interface, not a concrete type.

Relating to the code above, I was dwelling on why something like that last line (`const temp: A = temp1;`) was valid, through the veil of type intersection.

Taking the veil off, I realise that it's valid for good reason.

`A` is not a concrete type like a primitive or a class, it is an interface.

## Conclusion

To bring this all back to the original question...

TypeScript's `interface` and `readonly`, coupled with JavaScript's `Object.assign()` are the most you can get for compile-time type safety and immutability.

The rest of the checking responsibility must fall to practices such as unit testing, code review, etc..